# How to get my native module invoked before staticCompressionModule in IIS

Tags: c++, windows, iis-7, iis-8

In my native module i am handling onSendResponse event but chunk data which is coming is in compressed form because of that module is not able to process it .

With the help of [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis)  i found that staticCompressionModule is doing compression at MAP_REQUEST_HANDLER event before my module is getting triggered on onSendResponse event .

As I want to trigger my module before StaticCompression Module so i did this as described in the one article I found on MAP_REQUEST_HANDLE event .

pModuleInfo->SetPriorityForRequestNotification(
RQ_MAP_REQUEST_HANDLER,
PRIORITY_ALIAS_FIRST
);

after doing this also i can see StaticCompressionModule is getting triggered first . so i moved my module above staticCompressionModule in globalModules section in ApllicationHost.config file as suggested by article.
http://www.ksingla.net/2006/06/execution_order_of_modules_in_iis7/

still my module is getting invoked later . is there anything else I need to do ?

Comment: Have you tried to modify IIS module order list to move your native module ahead StaticCompressionModule?

Comment: @Jokies Ding , yes i have tried that at both global level and also application level.in ordered list i can see my module above staticCompressionModule